# Connect to Docker Postgres Container got connection timeout

Tags: postgresql, docker

So what i did is:

```
docker run -d -e POSTGRES_USER=user -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=456789 --name admin-service -p 5432:5432  postgres
```

and when i check with `docker ps` and docker `inspect`

```
"Networks": {
              ...
                    "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
              ...
             }
  }
```

and docker ps:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE      COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                    NAMES
6f1b75bed5b1   postgres   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   18 minutes ago   Up 18 minutes   0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp   admin-service
```

i went to PgAdmin and try to connect with host: `172.17.0.2`, i get connection time out, so i change hostname to `localhost`, it keep saying `password authentication failed`, i filled username and password as above. So i have no idea what i did wrong here.

Comment: If your pgadmin is running on the docker host, then you should be able to connect at `localhost` port `5432`.

Comment: i've tried that, and it keep warning that i failed to authenticate, i use ```user``` as username and ```456789``` as password

Answer (score 6):

found the problem, just change to another port, and it worked.

```
docker run --name admin-service -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=456789 -p 8001:5432 -d postgres
```

Comment: This actually fixed it for me as well

Comment: There has to be a reason why this is the only fix for this...

Comment: I got an error that says my db is used already

`docker: Error response from daemon: Conflict. The container name "/crowd_db_1" is already in use by container "fcba543286ee3f34a1ca9ba2b63469c44f2e2f87ca4fc20c14c55ce64901422c". You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name.`