# Why can't I connect to postgres container outside of docker-compose?

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, postgis, openstreetmap

I am doing (or planning to do) some spatial db work with OpenStreetMaps data using Postgres. I am working on a mac m1, and decided the best way is to run a Postgres db with PostGis installed in a docker container. I can't connect from my host machine, but I can connect from another container added in the same docker-compose.

In order to set the database up for importing OSM data, I need to change some of the config values, as well as install PostGis. So I have written my own dockerfile that completes these tasks  on startup. To do so I use a two .sh files. This dockerfile works mostly correctly, as I can connect from another docker container running pgadmin4, but my backend application, azure data studio, and psql from terminal cannot connect, getting `could not connect to server: Operation timed out Is the server running on host "172.31.0.2" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?`.

My assumption is that I'm missing or adding something incorrectly when I run the Postgres container  but no amount of googling bears fruit! Any help would be amazing.

## Docker compose

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  db:
    build:
      ./database
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
```

## Dockerfile

```
FROM postgres:14-bullseye

LABEL maintainer="PostGIS Project - https://postgis.net"

ENV POSTGIS_MAJOR 3
ENV POSTGIS_VERSION 3.3.2+dfsg-1.pgdg110+1

RUN apt-get update \
      && apt-cache showpkg postgresql-$PG_MAJOR-postgis-$POSTGIS_MAJOR \
      && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
           # ca-certificates: for accessing remote raster files;
           #   fix: https://github.com/postgis/docker-postgis/issues/307
           ca-certificates \
           \
           postgresql-$PG_MAJOR-postgis-$POSTGIS_MAJOR=$POSTGIS_VERSION \
           postgresql-$PG_MAJOR-postgis-$POSTGIS_MAJOR-scripts \
      && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN mkdir -p /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
COPY ./initdb-postgis.sh /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/10_postgis.sh
COPY ./update-postgis.sh /usr/local/bin
```

Essentially a copy of the postgis docker image, but that allows me to install other extensions in the initdb-postgis.sh and update-postgis.sh files, shown below:

## initdb-postgis.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e

export PGUSER="$POSTGRES_USER"

"${psql[@]}" <<- 'EOSQL'
ALTER SYSTEM SET listen_addresses = '*';
ALTER SYSTEM SET wal_level = minimal;
ALTER SYSTEM SET max_wal_senders = 0;
ALTER SYSTEM SET checkpoint_timeout = '1d';
ALTER SYSTEM SET checkpoint_completion_target = 0.90;
ALTER SYSTEM SET shared_buffers = '8GB';
ALTER SYSTEM SET max_wal_size = '10GB';
ALTER SYSTEM SET min_wal_size = '1GB';
CREATE DATABASE template_postgis IS_TEMPLATE true;
EOSQL

for DB in template_postgis "$POSTGRES_DB"; do
    echo "Loading PostGIS extensions into $DB"
    "${psql[@]}" --dbname="$DB" <<-'EOSQL'
        CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS postgis;
        CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS postgis_topology;
                CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS hstore;
EOSQL
done
```

## update-postgis.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e

export PGUSER="$POSTGRES_USER"

POSTGIS_VERSION="${POSTGIS_VERSION%%+*}"

for DB in template_postgis "$POSTGRES_DB" "${@}"; do
    echo "Updating PostGIS extensions '$DB' to $POSTGIS_VERSION"
    psql --dbname="$DB" -c "
        -- Upgrade PostGIS (includes raster)
        CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS postgis VERSION '$POSTGIS_VERSION';
        ALTER EXTENSION postgis UPDATE TO '$POSTGIS_VERSION';
        -- Upgrade Topology
        CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS postgis_topology VERSION '$POSTGIS_VERSION';
        ALTER EXTENSION postgis_topology UPDATE TO '$POSTGIS_VERSION';
        -- Upgrade hstore
        CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS hstore;
    "
```

I'm connecting from the host using the IP given when I docker inspect the container id, so the docker compose network shouldn't be an issue. As I mentioned before, connection works fine from inside the docker compose, with both a pgadmin4 and unix script running osm2pgsql. Both can connect using either the IP from docker inspect, or the name of the service, in this case 'db'.

Whilst I admit I am relitively inexperienced with both docker and postgis, normally some amount of googling helps me find the issue, but no this time - please help!

Comment: Instead of the IP given by inspect, try using `localhost`.

Comment: Hi @HansKilian, thanks for the quick reply. Unfortunately that gives me a different error - 'FATAL: role "postgres" does not exist'

Comment: It got you a step closer, as now you can connect. I don't know the solution to the error you get now. Maybe someone else can help?

Comment: This seems to connect me to another, local postgres database. I can connect to it using psql, but \dt and \du list none of the tables or users that exist in my docker hosted db. I can however see the correct tables when I enter the docker container and use psql.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that other processes (namely other postgres db's) were running on port 5432. So following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72569121/connect-to-docker-postgres-container-got-connection-timeout) fixed the issue, and I can now connect using psql.